# Pull chain pulling but not turning on and off lights

Tags: electrical

I have installed this pull chain on my bathroom light fixture. It's retracting but it's not turning on and off the lights like it should. When I installed it it worked it just stopped working now and it's only been a day since I installed it. The last pull chain I put on there stopped retracting within the first you hours of installation.

[image: Pull chain that I'm talking about]

Comment: Either pulling too hard and breaking them or buying the cheapest ones from ebay.

Comment: maybe you have to replace the switch, not just the pull chain

Comment: Define "installed pull chain". The switch is not operating, but whether the problem is the switch or your installation requires disassembling and inspection.

Comment: Can you confirm if just replacing the chain or the whole switch which has a pull chain.  Two switches failing that fast is odd(probably too cheap from places electric goods should not be brought from).  Just the chain might mean the switch is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Since we cannot see your wiring job it is possible that to be the problem.

There are three possibilities here.

One is as said before that the wiring became loose.

Second one is that the switch was overloaded by having too many lights on it.

Third one is the switch is simply bad.

To know if the switch is working you can hear a very clear clicking noise.